# What does i for i in s mean?

Tags: python

```
def CodelandUsernameValidation(s):
  if len(s)>4 and len(s)<25 and s[0].isalpha() and [i for i in s if i.isalnum() or i=="_"]!=[] and s[-1]!="_":
    return True
  else:
    return False
# keep this function call here 
print(CodelandUsernameValidation(input()))
```

Comment: look up list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

It's a `list comprehension` if you expand, it'll look like this ->

```
result = []
for i in s: # will fetch element one by one from iterable
    if i.isalnum() or i=="_": # checking condition
        result.append(i) # if true, then append it to the list
```

This above code can be rewritten as -

```
result = [i for i in s if i.isalnum() or i=="_"]
```

Answer (score 0):

That produces a list of those characters in `s` that are either alphanumeric or underlines.  The code is actually incorrect, because it will pass if ANY of the characters are alphanumeric or underline, whereas the intent surely was that ALL of the characters must be alphanumeric or underline.  Here's a better way to write it:

```
def CodelandUsernameValidation(s):
  return 4 < len(s) < 25 and s[0].isalpha() and all(i.isalnum() or i=='_' for i in s) and s[-1] != '_'

print(CodelandUsernameValidation(input()))
```